# How to call method with different time of intervals in iOS swift?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift

I have a method that method  prints 'Hello world' text but My task is that It has to print different time intervals. By using Timer we can call method every 5 minutes. But I need to Print that text as in different time Intervals like 0 minutes, 2 minutes and then every 5 minutes?

```
var seconds = 60 
var timer = Timer() 
var isTimerRunning = false //This will be used to make sure only one timer is created at a time.

func printHello()
{

print("Hello World");

}
```

How can I do this task? could anyone guide me to do this task

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```
func startRoutine() {
   // at 0
   printHello() 
   // after 2
   DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 120.0, execute: {
     self.printHello()
   })
   // after 7 every 5 
   DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 420.0, execute: {
     self.startTimer()
   })
}

func startTimer() {
   let timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 300, repeats: true) { (timer) in
      self.printHello()
   }
}
```

Comment: works like charm